# How to change php version in wamp?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, wamp

I am using Wamp 3.2 on Windows 10. After I install, it shows it's running php 7.3.12 on the server. But the cli shows php 5.6.40.
I firstly tried changing phpcli from 5.6.40 in wamp manager. I got the same result.
I then tried changing the environment variable. There is still no change. My cli is still showing php 5.6.40.
Unfortunately, this means I cannot run my frameworks such as Code Igniter 4.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: You could change the PATH in environnement variables to define the directory of the desired PHP version (restart the terminal after changing the PATH).

Comment: Tried that. I'm still getting v 5.6 in cli after restarting.

Comment: Since WAMP does not support PHP 7 by default, it is suggested to use XAMPP instead: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html (select the PHP version you want)

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the version path in the `Environment Variables` of the system. Follow the steps.

- This PC
- Properties
- Advanced system settings
- Advance
- **click** Environment Variables
- Set path in system veriables as screenshot
- then restart teminal

[image]

Comment: I tried doing that. I don't know if it's a wamp setting, but even when I add my prefered version of php to path variables and restart, cli is still showing 5.6 as my version.

Comment: Include only one path of the PHP version. Have you added multiple paths of the PHP version?

Comment: I made sure there was only one version in the path environment variables. It didn't work. I eventually managed to find a solution, I just forgot to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the variables and all that, my main problem was cli kept on identifying php 5 as my php version. Even when I changed the phpcli version in Wamp manager, it kept on doing the same. And it is impossible to install wamp without php 5 for some reason.

What finally worked was going to the bin\php folder. I then inserted an underscore "_" infront of the folder name of php 5.

After that, cli started showing the php version specified in path variables. I have no idea why it works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q6qE.jpg)

it contain in ^ icon in start bar when you click green icon then you ckick php then ckick change version up to you